# Using a stored variable as a parameter to the replaceWith() method in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am storing the value of a text-box in a variable as:

```
var myname=$('#test').val();
```

The value of `myname` is then used to replace an html tag `<div class="name"></div>` which sits in the following location:

```
<td>
   <div class="name"></div>
</td>
```

Then I used `$('.name').replaceWith(myname);` to get the final result as:

```
<td>
    **Value of myname**
</td>
```

..but I failed.

I also tried `$('.name').replaceWith('<div>'+myname+'</div>');` to no avail.

Please assist!

Comment: When replacing a HTML tag you should always replace it with valid HTML, ie. another HTML tag. Is the value of `#test` valid HTML, and remember that the value is what was typed in the input or selected in some other form element, not the contents of the element itself?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: `$('.name').replaceWith('<div>'+myname+'</div>');` should work (even if not best practice). Are you doing it inside of a document ready callback? `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of replacing the whole div, you should just set it's text content.

```
$('.name').text(myname);
```

Another benefit of this method is that you don't risk inserting arbitrary HTML into the page content, which would happen in your example if someone typed their name as `"<b>Hello!</b>"`

Comment: @MukundZare Do you have all of your code properly wrapped in a `ready` function?

Comment: @MukundZare Any code that works with DOM elements, meaning anything that uses a selector to look things up, will not work until the DOM has loaded. Therefore, all of that code should be placed inside of a ready function. Since you only posted a small portion of your code, I can't really give more guidance than that. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
$('.name').html(myname);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and this is working

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#lnk').click(function () {
            var myname = $('#test').val();

            $('.name').replaceWith('<div>' + myname + '<div>');
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="test" />
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="lnk">click here </a>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="name">aaa </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```